# Adding two different datatype in one index of ArrayList - java

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to store two different data types in arraylist ?

for example

```
 ArrayList<String,int> arr = new ArrayList<>();
```

if I want to store a string and integer into one index of an arrayList. How can I do that and how will I be able to access it?

Comment: no, you can't do that. Maybe a Map could fit

Comment: By creating a composite object that contains ... a String and an Integer, and by storing that

Comment: No. an Array<> does not suppl anything other than Int or Long as keys.
What you are looking for is a Map<String, Integer> .

Comment: @Gewure there is no such thing as an Array<>, there is an ArrayList, though, which can contain a lot more compared to just an Int (which doesn't exist -> Integer) or a Long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you should include both (the string and the integer) in one object having the string and integer as fields. It could look like:

```
public class StringAndInteger {
  public String string;
  public Integer integer;
}
```

I suggest giving it a meaningful name, setting the fields private and add getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it list of lists.

```
        List<List<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(Arrays.asList("str1", 8));
    list.add(Arrays.asList("str91", 98));

    System.out.println(list);
```

Of course, a better way would be to use Map instead of this. Also you cannot use primitive type with collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList uses Array as its under-lying data structure, which can not add heterogeneous data-types. To achieve so, Just Make a class in your code. Declare the instance variables in this class. If you want to add String and Integer Then write it like this:

public class YourClass{
//Your code
...

//Create a class in your existing class. It is just used like a data-type.
static class SampleClass {
  public String str;
  public Integer intgr;
}

//Now You can use this class like a data-type
public void myMethod(){
ArrayList<SampleClass> myList=new ArrayList();
//add values.
SampleClass ob1=new SampleClass('name1',12345);
SampleClass ob2=new SampleClass('name2',12345234);
myList.add(ob1);
myList.add(ob2);
myList.add(new SampleClass('name3', 12));

//get values
for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
String stringValue=myList.get(i).str;
String intValue=myList.get(i).intgr;
system.out.println(stringValue);
system.out.println(intValue);
}
}
```